# Trying to combine 2 columns into one distinct result

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate 2 rows, from different tables into one result. this is the code I currently have...

```
    SELECT CONCAT(C.Correct_Answer, I.Incorrect_Answers) AS Answers
FROM Cor_A AS C, Inc_A AS I
```

and this is what it returns

```
Answers
----------------------------
45
410
450
4Green
4Red
4Potato
4Yellow
40
42
```

This is, however, not what I want. 
How do I get them to return in separate records?

```
4
5
10
50
Green
Red
Potato
Yellow
```

(What should be "Blue")

any help is appreciated guys, as you can tell, I'm pretty new...

Comment: use union ..

select col1 from A
union col2 from B

Comment: you don't have a JOIN condition. and also you don't have a separator in the CONCAT function.

Comment: you need to JOIN your two tables on an answerID field?

Comment: Can you show us your current table structures?  That will go a long way towards helping us help you.

Comment: what about last 40 and 42 you don't need that

Comment: if you want to get rid of 4 value then simply do the replace ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will eventually return all the records in both fields but if a record is common it return only one record

```
SELECT Correct_Answer as Answer 
  FROM Cor_A 
UNION 
SELECT Incorrect_Answers 
  FROM Inc_A;
```